# vscode (linux) terminal "command not found"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Problem: seems like the terminal in VSCode is looking for the commands in the wrong location. at the moment I am having trouble with running the command "gulp".

When i run eg: "gulp watch" in my system terminal it runs my function watch as it should.

When I run the same command in vscode I get an "command not found"

I have tried: I first noticed it when node/npm/gulp stopped working. I uninstalled all completely, removing old folders etc and reinstall them. Problem persisted though, so I cd'ed into to /usr/bin/ and created an ln to the node/npm installs this seemed to solve the problem for npm/node. But I am having trouble with my gulp-cli. It's installed globally and can be run without issue in the normal system terminal. But when I try to run it from the terminal in vs code (it is set to use BASH, already checked that) I get a "command not found" error and making a link to it like I did with npm/node does not work.

Any and all advice welcome.

Comment: Your description does not make clear what you are trying and what the problem is. Show as a minimal reproducible example. The steps you did to solve the problem look more like are able to make it worse.

Comment: @KlausD.tried to modify my post hope it helps

Comment: check the value of PATH in your two terminals (the one that works and the one that doesn't) - are they the same?

Comment: @topsail not sure what you mean it's installed globally and even with the same path (guessing your referring to current dir path) it still says unknown command. Meaning that I cannot do a "which gulp" since it isn't a known command. But maybe your referring to something else?

Comment: I am referring to your PATH environment variable. Typically in bash you set these values when the shell starts. In your bash shell you would issue the command `echo $PATH` - the path list all the locations where bash will "look" for programs that it can run. If you type the name of a program and it is not in any of these locations - that is the cause of the "command not found" error. E.g. see: [how-to-view-and-update-the-linux-path-environment-variable](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-view-and-update-the-linux-path-environment-variable)

Comment: I have no explanation as to why, but here is how I "solved" it: after installing node gulp etc. I restarted, after doing that node gulp etc was missing from the system. I was quite confused about this but I reinstalled them again and now when I call gulp from vscode, it just works.. and a restart doesn't magically remove them from the system. I suspect a system 76 update might be to blame for all my trouble.. it's the only explanation I have.

but thanks @topsail you tought me something about the bash,, maybe it's about time I go on a deep dive and learn more about the topic, thanks :)